# PHP regex match in file content

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have a few files I'm gathering according to their "age" (last two days) and I now need to extract text from them following a regexp pattern (in this case, the pattern it's like a microsoft product key), here's what I've done so far:

```
<?php

$files = iterator_to_array(
    new GlobIterator('/var/www/log/access.log.*', GlobIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME) );

foreach ($files as $file) {
        $filelastmodified = filemtime($file);
                if((time()-$filelastmodified) < 48*3600 && is_file($file))
                {
                $regexp = '/^[A-Z1-9]{5}(-[A-Z1-9]{5}){4}$/';
                preg_match_all($regexp, file($file), $keys, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
                }

}
print_r($keys, true);

?>
```

But I'm getting an error:

> PHP Warning:  preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array
>   given in /var/www/log/keys.php on line 11

What am I doing wrong?
Also, I'd like to know if it possible to save those matched text strings uniquely, meaning if a key appears twice I only need it saved once into the array.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [PHP.net file manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) `array file ( string $filename [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )` Returns array. Since **expects parameter 2 to be string** this is not right.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong. Didn't you read it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function returns with an array, try `file_get_contents($file)` instead. Then you can use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove duplicate entries:

```
preg_match_all($regexp, file_get_contents($file), $keys, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$keys = array_unique($keys);
```

**Edit:**

Use another variable to collect array values then you can remove duplicates easily. The full code:

```
<?php

$files = iterator_to_array(
        new GlobIterator('/var/www/log/access.log.*', GlobIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME) );

$allkey = Array();
foreach ($files as $file) {
        $filelastmodified = filemtime($file);
        if((time()-$filelastmodified) < 48*3600 && is_file($file))
        {
                $regexp = '/([A-Z]{5}(-[A-Z]{5}){4})/';
                preg_match_all($regexp, file_get_contents($file), $keys, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
                $allkey = array_merge($allkey, $keys[1]);
        }
}
$allkey = array_unique($allkey);
print_r($allkey);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already understood that from the previous comment by @Basje.
But now I still get an empty array, so I guess something is going wring on the regexp matching...
Here's an example of a line on the file:
    **192.168.1.4 - - [11/Jun/2013:06:25:40 +0300] "GET http://mysite.com/update.php?gse=SRINO-ZKPGV-PSHJO-KXCOJ-BNKBP&gsm=d2bc6b3572d8fc2cc7cf983c9069ab2e HTTP/1.1" 200 6066 "-" "-"**

Comment: It seems that the file does not content data that matches the regexp. Or try evaluate the file row-by-row: `$file = file($file); foreach($file as $row) { preg_match_all($regexp, $row, $keys, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER); $allkey = array_merge($allkey, $keys); }`

Comment: It does, just that when I added the comment with the line sample it parsed it as a hyperlink, if you hover with the mouse on "mysite.com/" you will see the rest, here's the line again without the domain name:
**192.168.1.4 - - [11/Jun/2013:06:25:39 +0300] "GET domainnamehere/update.php?gse=JHSSM-QAYLT-JNKJM-ESFOH-RNMKS&gsm=0e84c8552f630ede6e82673eb4123b8b HTTP/1.1" 200 6242 "-" "-"**

Comment: Well, then the regexp should not contain the start `^` and end `$` signs: `/[A-Z1-9]{5}(-[A-Z1-9]{5}){4}/`. Try this with the row-by-row parsing.

Comment: Yes, but then it will bring me the whole line, right? I only need the keys extracted, not the whole line.
Another correction, I've just noticed that in this case, the key doesn't contain any numbers, only letters, so the regexp should be 
`/[A-Z]{5}(-[A-Z]{5}){4}/`
This didn't solve my problem though... :-(
EDIT: the "^" and "$" suppression didn't help, still got nothing in result

Comment: It should find only the key, but it is good idea to use brackets to get the variables... `([A-Z]{5}(-[A-Z]{5}){4})`. Then the `$keys[1]` will contains the codes: `$allkey = array_merge($allkey, $keys[1]);`

Comment: I'm getting lost here, man!
I did what you suggested and now the script runs for a long time, it looks like it's stuck.
Didn't get the $keys[1] one either.
I don't know, perhaps my approach is too complicated?
All I know is I have a few log files, normally 2 files, those of today and yesterday ones, but there could be more, depending on the size rotation.
So what I need is tor extract the keys out of those files that are not older than two days and store them all uniquely in an array for later processing.

Comment: OK, I modified the whole code above, and in this form it may work.

Comment: YAY! It works!
I was about to reach the same results with this approach, but you saved me time and did it faster and better!
You rock @Stocki, thank you very much!